# Routing in Asp.net Core using AngularJs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ngroute

I am fairly new to the Asp.Net. So anyways, what I want to achieve/do is I want to control the routing in Asp.net Core using AngularJs. But the problem is I can't load(?) the page(s) I want. The pages are not showing in the ng-view. or am i doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here some of my code:

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<body  ng-app="myApp" style="background-color:white">
<div ng-controller="Test">
<h1 style="margin-left:20px;color:darkred">Test</h1>
<input ng-model="test"/>
<p>{{tester}}</p>
<p style="color:black">{{test}}</p>
    </div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#routeOne">Route One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#routeTwo">Route Two</a></li>

</ul>
<div>
    <p>@Model.test_name</p>
    <p>@Model.test_role</p>


</div>
<div ng-view></div>

<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()


</div>
</body>
```

HomeController.cs:

```
namespace WebApplication12.controllers
 {
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MysqlConnector test = new MysqlConnector();
        return View(test);
    }

  }
 }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "One";
}

 <p> {{tester}}  test</p>
```

Index1.cshtml:

```
 @{

   ViewData["Title"] = "Second";

 }

 <p>Second</p>
```

site.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('Test', function ($scope) {

    $scope.tester = "message displayed";

});

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
     when('/routeOne', {
        template: '<p>First Page</p>',
        controller: "Test"
     })
    .when('/routeTwo', {
        templateUrl: 'Index1.cshtml',
        controller: "Test"

    })

 }]);
```

p.s: test_name and test_role are from mysql server they are working fine.

p.s 2: I cut the scripts part in layout. so scripts are working/loaded correctly.

Comment: What is your current url ? Did you tried `yourBaseUrl/routeOne` ?

Comment: I am running this on http://localhost:60660. I have tried it but it's showing empty page. When I click on the links the url becomes like this. http://localhost:60660/#!#routeOne

Comment: add `<base href="/">` in the `<head>` part of the _layout

Comment: I have added it but still nothing. Added "!" to "/" and directed me to the page(empty page).

Comment: I have added my code to github: https://github.com/Blakingale/angularjs_routing_aspnetcore

Answer (score 0):

Your templateUrl in the $routeProvider-Configuration for /routeTwo has to point to the url of the ASP.NET Core controller action e.g. "/home/index". The given "index1.cshtml" is a Razor template that has to be processed and served by the ASP.NET Core Framework via the controler method.

I suggest to change

```
.when('/routeTwo', {
    templateUrl: 'Index1.cshtml',
    controller: "Test"
```

to

```
.when('/routeTwo', {
        templateUrl: '/home/index',
        controller: "Test"
```